# hide and show edit link based on condition(true and false) MVC (html grid)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

here is the code of Cshtml: go through code

I want to hide the  **Edit link** only on page load if the value of

- **IS_CONFIRM ?true(Hide):false(Show)**

I am using MVC @Html.Grid:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
       columns.Add(a => a.BL_No).Titled("B/L Number").Filterable(true).Encoded(false)
       .Sanitized(false).SetWidth(50);
       columns.Add(a => a.BL_DATE).Titled("B/L Date").Filterable(true).Encoded(false)
       .Sanitized(false).SetWidth(50);
       columns.Add(a => a.BOOKING_REF_NO).Titled("Booking Ref No").Filterable(true).Encoded(false)
       .Sanitized(false).SetWidth(50);
       columns.Add(a => a.CARGO_DESCRIPTION).Titled("Cargo Description").Filterable(true).Encoded(false)
       .Sanitized(false).SetWidth(50);
       columns.Add(a => a.CRO_NO).Titled("CRO Number").Filterable(true).Encoded(false)
       .Sanitized(false).SetWidth(50);
       columns.Add(c => c.ETA).Titled("ETA").Filterable(true).Encoded(false)
       .Sanitized(false).SetWidth(50);
       columns.Add(c => c.ETD).Titled("ETD").Filterable(true).Encoded(false)
       .Sanitized(false).SetWidth(50);
       columns.Add(a => a.IS_CONFIRM, true).Titled("CheckBox").Filterable(true).Encoded(false)
       .Sanitized(false).SetWidth(50);

       columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(20).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditBillOfLading", new { BL_ID = o.BL_ID})).Titled("Edit");
       columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(20).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("PrintBillofLading", "BillofladingReport", new { BL_ID = o.BL_ID }, new { target = "_blank" })).Titled("Action1");
       columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(20).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("PrintTerminal", "TerminalReport", new { BL_ID = o.BL_ID }, new { target = "_blank" })).Titled("Action2");
       //columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(20).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("BillofladingReport", new { BL_ID = o.BL_ID })).Titled("PrintProforma");
   }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
```

Comment: what do you want to hide ? a IS_CONFIRM column ?

Comment: IS_CONFIRM IS A CHECKBOX. IF CHECK BOX VALUE IS TRUE .I WANT TO HIDE  EDIT BUTTON

Answer (score 0):

You can add `class` attribute to `Edit` link like this:

```
columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(20).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditBillOfLading", new {@class="editLink"}, new { BL_ID = o.BL_ID})).Titled("Edit");
```

Then call `hide()` or `show()` in `page load` like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#IS_CONFIRM').prop("checked"))
            $('.editLink').hide();
        else
            $('.editLink').show();
    });
</script>
```